# Confusion regarding the series for true anomaly on Wikipedia

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I hope this is the right place to ask. Please point me elsewhere if that is not it the case.

I'm trying to calculate the position of Earth in its orbit given the day of the year. I found this Wikipedia page about the equation of the center:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_the_center

It includes a formula for an infinite series that is supposed to equal the true anomaly given the mean anomaly and the eccentricity of the orbit. I tried to implement it in Python using a finite number of terms, but I ran into an issue. The series uses an order `s-p` Bessel function, but because `s` and `p` are both summation indices that start at 1 and go toward infinity, `s-p` is sometimes less than 0. The page also provides a formula for the series that equals the Bessel function given its order. But that series includes a factorial of the value of the order, and as far as I understand, a factorial of a negative number is not defined. This resulted in an exception being thrown when trying to run my script.

What am I doing wrong or misinterpreting? Is there a better way to go about calculating this?

For full context, my goal is to write a script that (ignoring the rotation of the Earth) takes a latitude `l1`, and a day of year `d1`. Then for a given second latitude `l2` calculates at what day of year `d2` the angle of incidence of sun rays at `l2` matches the angle of incidence of sun rays at `l1` at `d1`.

Comment: Why are torturing yourself (and your computer, too)? Solve Kepler's equation for the eccentric anomaly, compute the true anomaly from the eccentric anomaly, and finally compute the difference between the true and mean anomalies.

Comment: Unless you're attempting to solve it that way for some specific reason, there are other methods of getting the Earth's position.  Like David said above, solving Kepler's Equation is one, probably the easiest is using VSOP87A at whatever precision level you need.  https://github.com/gmiller123456/vsop87-multilang

Comment: Just to be a math weenie, you can take the factorial of a negative number using the gamma function: https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/factorials-and-the-gamma-function-4350 though I have no idea whether this will work in your formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the factorial breaks down for negative order. However, given $J_{-m}(x)$ for any whole number $m$, you can formally take the limit of $J_{-a}(x)$ as $a$ approaches $m$, treating $x$ as a parameter. This introduces noninteger factorials in the series for $J_{-a}(x)$; to handle that the factorial of a noninteger is defined via the [gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html). The net result of such a limiting operation is

$J_{-m}(x)=(-1)^mJ_{m}(x).$

Thus, put that equation in when you encounter a negative integer order for the Bessel function.

Comment: See the mathworld.wolfram.com page on [Bessel functions of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) for a derivation of $J_{-m}(x) = (-1)^mJ_m(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative that doesn't use that series, do the following:

- Solve Kepler's equation, $M = E - e \sin E$, for the eccentric anomaly. Newton-Raphson iteration is fairly fast. For large eccentricity values use $E=\pi$ as an initial guess. This converges for all eccentricity values between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). For sufficiently small eccentricity values, using $E=M$ as an initial guess also always converges and results in a faster convergence.
- Solve for the true anomaly given the eccentric anomaly. Use $$\tan\left(\frac{\nu}2\right) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1+e}{1-e}\right)} \tan\left(\frac{E}2\right)$$
- The equation of center is the difference between the true anomaly and the mean anomaly, $\nu-M$.

A simple python script follows.

```
  def equation_of_center_from_M(M, e) :
      # Place M in [0,2*pi)
      M -= math.floor(M/twopi)*twopi

      # Solve Kepler's equation for eccentric anomaly
      if e > 0.5 :
          E = math.pi
      else :
          E = M
    while True :
        delta = (M - (E - e*math.sin(E))) / (1.0 - e*math.cos(E))
        E += delta
        if abs(delta) <= 1e-15*E : break

    # Solve for true anomaly given the eccentric anomaly
    nu = 2.0*math.atan(math.sqrt((1.0+e)/(1.0-e))*math.tan(0.5*E))
    if nu < 0.0 : nu += twopi

    return nu-M
```

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article on the [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) states that

> α and −α produce the same differential equation

α being the order of the function. Computing the absolute value of α before using it in the calculation seems to produce reasonable orbital motion, so I believe that this was the piece of information that I was missing. I'm not an expert however, so I cannot verify whether it is correct.

Comment: This is incorrect in that, while the absolute value of what the Bessel function evaluates to will remain the same regardless of whether the order is positive or negative, the sign of the result depends on the order, as described in Oscar's answer.